# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" when reading JSON into state

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, setstate

I know this question has been asked before, but I've tried all the suggested solutions and none of them work (which might, admittedly, be down to me being a numpty).

Anywho, my particular problem is that the following line is causing the error ('TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined'): this.setState({pictures : response, loading: false});

FWIW, the previous line is a console.log call that tells me that the response has come back OK.

Here's the code in its entirety:

import {Component} from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import {Checkbox, CheckboxGroup} from 'react-checkbox-group';
import Thumbs from './Thumbs';

class Search extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        loading: false,
        images: false,
        audio: false,
        pictures: []
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    this.style = {backgroundColor: 'green'}
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const search = e.target[0].value;
    const vid = e.target[1].checked;
    const aud = e.target[2].checked;

    var medium = "image";

    if (aud) {
        medium = "audio";
    }

    var endPoint = "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=" + search + "&media_type=" + medium;
    console.log(endPoint);
    fetch(endPoint)
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.status >= 400) {
                throw new Error("Bad response from server");
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({pictures : response, loading: false});                //PROBLEM IS HERE
        });

}


render() {
    const { pictures, loading } = this.state
    function mediaChanged(newMedia) {
        if (newMedia.length === 2) {
            newMedia.shift();
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="search">
            <h1>NASA Search</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="search" width="60" placeholder="search term(s)"/><br/><br/>
                <CheckboxGroup
                    name="media"
                    onChange={mediaChanged}>
                    <label><Checkbox value="images"/> Images</label>
                    <label><Checkbox value="audio"/> Audio</label>
                </CheckboxGroup>
            </form>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            {(pictures.length) ?
                pictures.map(
                    (pictures, i) =>
                        <Thumb key={i}/>
                ) :
                <span>-</span>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default Search

Comment: Context issue. Use `(response) => ` . Here `this` pointer will be binded automatically.

Comment: Madhavan, you're a star.
Thanks.